# WordPress Query with Array using LIKE

Tags: wordpress

I have a query that looks like this:

```
$data = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'custom_type',
        'post_status' =>  'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 200,
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' =>'_customer_start',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key'     => '_customer_id',
         'value'   => $customer_id,
         'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
        array(
         'key'     => '_customer_start',
         'value'   => $_customer_start,
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

The input to this query is two arrays:

```
$customer_id = array(2808,2814);
$_customer_start = array('20170212','20170224');
```

My issue is, this generates the following error:

```
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ..../wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php on line 597
```

I have troubleshot this and it would appear the issue is the second array, passing in a group of dates for a LIKE comparison. I cannot use an IN comparison (As is recommend for arrays) as the dates stored include times. Hence if I use an IN or EQUALS, I will not find them.

Is there a way of passing an array for LIKE comparison, without dynamically expanding the query?